# How to get a parametrization for a line?

Tags: integration, analysis

I am currently studying for some exams about line integrals. And I am struggling to get the parametrization for given problems.

For example the line of the following Ellipse $ {x^2 \over a^2} + {y^2 \over b^2} = 1; \; (x,y \ge 0) $

Well, I know the line would be: $ \gamma:[0, {\pi \over 2}] \to \mathbb{R}^2, \;  \gamma(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
        a \cos(t) \\
        b \cos(t) \\
\end{pmatrix}$

But how would I go for any given formula?

Also there was a problem given, to calculate a bug would travel, when it sits at the outer side of a wheel, which spins three times. I was able to find the following formula:

$ \gamma(t) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
t - \sin(t) \\
1 - \cos(t)
\end{pmatrix}
$

But how do I came up with these on my own?

Comment: Your $\gamma(t)$ isn't a line. In fact it traces out the given ellipse. You could use that and derivative to get a tangent line to the ellipse at a specific point on the ellipse.

Comment: Your objects are normally called "curves". (The term "line" usually connotes a Euclidean line, namely a locus $ax +by + c = 0$ in $\mathbf{R}^2$ with $a$, $b$ not both zero, or the set of points $\mathbf{x}_0 + t\mathbf{v}$ with $\mathbf{v}$ a non-zero vector and $t$ real.) Parametrizing a curve amounts to using a real number to describe a general point on your curve; this is more of an Art (examples, idioms, inspired tricks) than a Science (algorithms).

Comment: Regarding "Art", you'll want to be comfortable with lines, circles, and function graphs, and with how to "deform" a given parametrization (e.g., the way you described the ellipse), or how to "superpose" two types of motion (e.g., the cycloid as uniform circular motion superposed with the linear motion of the center of a wheel). A doable, non-trivial exercise is to describe a hypocycloid, the path of a small circle rolling without slipping inside a larger circle.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I was confused by the WP article *Line Integral*, where it says "*a line integral (sometimes called a ... curve integral*". But curve would be the direct translation to what our German professor used (Kurve). But are your saying, that there is nothing to learn for me? Only gain experience working with them?

Comment: To a "zero-th approximation", practice and experience with examples "should" be enough. Your professor would be a better person to ask, of course. (On a tangent, English is not the most consistent language; "curve integral" sounds strange, though it's more logical than "line integral". :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a general answer on how to parametrize a curve, but an "answer by extended example" (with exercises) that illustrates several "standard" ideas.

The position of a point $p$ on a unit circle that rolls to the right (at constant unit speed, and without slipping) along a horizontal line can be viewed as the "superposition" of the location of the center $c$ of the circle with the position of $p$ relative to $c$.

To give a parametrization, let the line be the horizontal coordinate axis, and locate the vertical axis so that $p$ touches the origin at time $0$. In these coordinates, the center $c$ starts at $(0, 1)$ and moves to the right at unit speed, so at time $t$, the center $c$ is located at $(t, 1)$. Because the circle has unit radius, the point $p$ has rotated *clockwise* by angle $t$ about $c$; that is, the *displacement* from $c$ to $p$ is
$$
\bigl(\cos(-\tfrac{\pi}{2} - t), \sin(-\tfrac{\pi}{2} - t)\bigr)
  = (-\sin t, -\cos t)
  = -(\sin t, \cos t).
$$
The location of $p$ at time $t$ in the fixed coordinate system is the vector sum
$$
\bigl(x(t), y(t)\bigr)
  = (t, 1) - (\sin t, \cos t)
  = (t - \sin t, 1 - \cos t).
$$

Once this description is available, it's easy to generalize. For posterity, here are some practice questions:

1. Modify the preceding formulas if the wheel rolls to the right with constant speed $v$; to the left with constant speed $v$; if the wheel rolls so that the velocity of its center at time $t$ is $v(t)$. (For the last part, a definite integral is needed.)
2. Modify the cycloid formulas (i) to describe the motion of a point on the rim of a circular wheel of radius $R > 0$ that rolls with constant speed $v$; (ii) to describe the motion of a point $p$ on the same wheel, but assuming $p$ lies at distance $r > 0$ from the center (i.e., not necessarily on the rim).
3. Let $0 < r < R$ be real numbers. Modify the preceding argument to describe the position of a point $p$ on the rim of of a circular wheel of radius $r$ that rolls (at unit angular speed counterclockwise, without slipping) inside a circle of radius $R$.

Selected answers:

1.

> Put $\theta(t) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} v(\tau)\, d\tau$. (If $v$ is constant, $\theta(t) = vt$.) The position of $p$ at time $t$ is $$\bigl(x\circ\theta(t), y\circ\theta(t)\bigr) = \bigl(\theta(t) - \sin \theta(t), 1 - \cos \theta(t)\bigr).$$

2.

> The position of $p$ at time $t$ is $$\bigl(x(t), y(t)\bigr) = (vt, R) - r\bigl(\sin(vt/R), \cos(vt/R)\bigr) = \bigl(vt - r\sin(vt/R), R - r\cos(vt/R)\bigr).$$

3.

> Let $R_{0} = R - r$. Choosing coordinates so $p$ is initially at $(R, 0)$, at time $t$ the center $c$ of the wheel is located at $(R_{0}\cos t, R_{0}\sin t)$, and the point $p$ has rotated *clockwise* about $c$ through angle $tR_{0}/r$ (*not* $tR/r$; why?; thus $$\bigl(x(t), y(t)\bigr) = \bigl(R_{0}\cos t + r\cos(tR_{0}/r), R_{0}\sin t - r\sin(tR_{0}/r)\bigr).$$